# phonegap.js and jq.ui.min.js together

Tags: cordova, appmobi

I am trying to make an app using the [phoneGap XDK from appmobi](http://www.appmobi.com/?q=node/153). I want to make a camera using the phoneGap library (phonegap.js), and all the other things (buttons etc.) in the app I want to make by using jquery.ui.min.js library. In the simulation I haven't any problems, but in an android mobile browser it doesn't work. I want to know if i can use these two libraries together in a phoneGap XDK program, and if yes how can I make it to work on android phone?
Your help is very important to me.
Thank you.

In my HTML file I want to have these libraries:

```
http://localhost:58888/_appMobi/appmobi.js
http://localhost:58888/_appMobi/xhr.js
http://localhost:58888/_appMobi/phonegap.js
jq.ui.min.js
all.js
js/jq.web.min.js
```

Comment: I asked a similar question here http://forums.appmobi.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=1950&start=0

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the appMobi JavaScript bootstrap library can help you: http://dev.appmobi.com/?q=node/85

Review the implementation guide